# Http call Node.js problem, socket hang up error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, axios

I have encountered the following problem, all the HTTP calls through axios were working fine without any problem, since a couple of hours, all the calls have returned the following error:

```
socket hang up error
```

the strange thing is that from Postman the same call works without problems, I would like to know if any of you encountered the same problem and how you have solved it, here is the code I am using:

```
const getToken = async (username, password) => {
  try {
    const body = {username, password}
    const url = `${API_URI.auth}`
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(body)
    }
    const response = await axios(options).then((res) => res.data.json())
    console.log(response)
    return response
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you are still sending back a status in _all_ cases in your express app? This is most likely a server-side problem.

Comment: Yes, I already checked it, what seems strange to me is that through postman or any other place the call is made without problem